# Should data be clustered as databases or collections

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

We would have date specific trading data for about 10M trades - each day's data comprising ~1T data in different collections like market,trade,settlements etc.
Since we would not need more than 3 days data at any point of time - intention is to delete all data pertaining to T-3 or more.
There would be 2 possible options:

```
1.Each trading  day being represented as a separate database  - with the standard set of collections viz marketdata,trade,settlementdata in each database
2.Every collection being appended with the date viz marketdata_10032019,marketdata_10042019 etc
```

The first option seems better as:

```
1. much cleaner in terms of maintenance - just dropping the obsolete databases,rather than scanning collections by name. 
2. Dynamic collection names as in second option puts severe restrictions in aggregation possibilities - mongo aggregation does not support dynamic names.
```

Would appreciate further views   - based on performance,concurrency,scalability,clustering/sharding,maintenance etc

All earlier questions do not address the used case of maintaining a  second-level  logically aggregated grouping of collections based on date

Comment: *"All earlier questions do not address the used case of maintaining a second-level logically aggregated grouping of collections based on date"* - Well yeah they really do. As a bit of general advice, simply adding a simple *"the duplicate does not address by question"* statement to your question is not sufficient grounds for reopening. I would only ever reopen a question marked to a duplicate when there is a significant example that the demonstrated process in the answer does not provide a solution in a specific case. For such a *general* question, that clearly is not possible here. Accept it.

Comment: And to be clear. In it's present form the question would be way **too broad** even if you disagree with it being a direct duplicate. So we don't reopen questions from one reason just to close as another. I do disagree here and certainly believe there is much you can learn from the marked duplicate and further research on the subjects explained within. In fact "which is best" is **only** ever accurately obtained for rigorous testing to determine which actually performs **best for you**. Really does not need unfounded opinions.